# Infinite functions in parallel

Tags: .net, asynchronous, f#, parallel-processing

I have a function that executes in following manner:

```
while true
  [do something]
  [sleep]
```

Now I want to start multiple threads that will do the same logic.

I tried with wrapping my functions in async {} and piping results in `Async.Parallel` and `Async.RunSynchronously` but I get only the first function in the list working.

I tried to boil down my problems to following example:

```
[1..100]
|> Seq.map (fun x -> 
    async {
        Thread.Sleep(1000)
        printfn "%i" x
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromHours(1.))})
|> Async.Parallel
|> Async.Ignore
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

I would like here to get all the numbers printed after 1 second and then wait for 1h for all threads to finish. But it takes much longer and I get numbers printed one by one in period of couple of minutes.

One solution is to pipe my collection to

```
|> Array.map (fun x -> Task.Factory.StartNew(fun () -> domystuff x))
|> Task.WaitAll
```

Is that the proper way to achieve this? I can go with Thread.Start of course but I would like something more F#-ish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get your desired results using [`Async.Sleep`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370508.aspx) instead of `Thread.Sleep`:

```
[1..100]
|> Seq.map (fun x -> 
    async {
        do! Async.Sleep(1000)
        printfn "%i" x
        do! Async.Sleep(int (TimeSpan.FromHours(1.).TotalMilliseconds))})
|> Async.Parallel
|> Async.Ignore
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Comment: I used Thread.Sleep because my real operation doesn't implement async. so I cannot use do!.

Comment: If you're not using async, then you shouldn't use Async. Try System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel instead.

Comment: Asynchronous workflows don't assure you that each task will be executed in a different thread (neither when requesting threads from the `ThreadPool` btw), so maybe this is why you are getting weird results.